# Pytorch CPU CUDA device load without gpu

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I found this nice code Pytorch mobilenet which I cant get running on a CPU.
https://github.com/rdroste/unisal

I am new to Pytorch so I am not shure what to do.

In line 174 of the module train.py the device is set:

```
device = 'cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
```

which is correct as far as I know about Pytorch.

**Do I have to change the torch.load too? I tried with no success.**

```
class BaseModel(nn.Module):
    """Abstract model class with functionality to save and load weights"""

    def forward(self, *input):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def save_weights(self, directory, name):
        torch.save(self.state_dict(), directory / f'weights_{name}.pth')

    def load_weights(self, directory, name):
        self.load_state_dict(torch.load(directory / f'weights_{name}.pth'))

    def load_best_weights(self, directory):
        self.load_state_dict(torch.load(directory / f'weights_best.pth'))

    def load_epoch_checkpoint(self, directory, epoch):
        """Load state_dict from a Trainer checkpoint at a specific epoch"""
        chkpnt = torch.load(directory / f"chkpnt_epoch{epoch:04d}.pth")
        self.load_state_dict(chkpnt['model_state_dict'])

    def load_checkpoint(self, file):
        """Load state_dict from a specific Trainer checkpoint"""
        """Load """
        chkpnt = torch.load(file)
        self.load_state_dict(chkpnt['model_state_dict'])

    def load_last_chkpnt(self, directory):
        """Load state_dict from the last Trainer checkpoint"""
        last_chkpnt = sorted(list(directory.glob('chkpnt_epoch*.pth')))[-1]
        self.load_checkpoint(last_chkpnt)
```

**I don’t get it. Where do I have to tell pytorch there is no gpu ?**

complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 99, in <module>
    fire.Fire()

  File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/unisal36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 138, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)

  File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/unisal36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 471, in _Fire
    target=component.__name__)

  File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/unisal36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 675, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)

  File "run.py", line 95, in predict_examples
    example_folder, is_video, train_id=train_id, source=source)

  File "run.py", line 72, in predictions_from_folder
    folder_path, is_video, source=source, model_domain=model_domain)

  File "/home/b256/Data/saliency_models/unisal-master/unisal/train.py", line 871, in generate_predictions_from_path
    self.model.load_best_weights(self.train_dir)

  File "/home/b256/Data/saliency_models/unisal-master/unisal/train.py", line 1057, in model
    self._model = model_cls(**self.model_cfg)

  File "/home/b256/Data/saliency_models/unisal-master/unisal/model.py", line 190, in __init__
    self.cnn = MobileNetV2(**self.cnn_cfg)

  File "/home/b256/Data/saliency_models/unisal-master/unisal/models/MobileNetV2.py", line 156, in __init__
    Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'weights/mobilenet_v2.pth.tar')

  File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/unisal36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 367, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)

  File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/unisal36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 538, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()

  File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/unisal36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 504, in persistent_load
    data_type(size), location)

  File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/unisal36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 113, in default_restore_location
    result = fn(storage, location)

  File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/unisal36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 94, in _cuda_deserialize
    device = validate_cuda_device(location)

  File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/unisal36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 78, in validate_cuda_device
    raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location='cpu' to map your storages to the CPU.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-on-gpu-load-on-cpu you'll see there's a `map_location` keyword argument to send weights to the proper device:

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location=device))
```

From the docs https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html#torch.load

> torch.load() uses Python’s unpickling facilities but treats storages,
> which underlie tensors, specially. They are first deserialized on the
> CPU and are then moved to the device they were saved from. If this
> fails (e.g. because the run time system doesn’t have certain devices),
> an exception is raised. However, storages can be dynamically remapped
> to an alternative set of devices using the map_location argument.
>
> If map_location is a callable, it will be called once for each
> serialized storage with two arguments: storage and location. The
> storage argument will be the initial deserialization of the storage,
> residing on the CPU. Each serialized storage has a location tag
> associated with it which identifies the device it was saved from, and
> this tag is the second argument passed to map_location. The builtin
> location tags are 'cpu' for CPU tensors and 'cuda:device_id' (e.g.
> 'cuda:2') for CUDA tensors. map_location should return either None or
> a storage. If map_location returns a storage, it will be used as the
> final deserialized object, already moved to the right device.
> Otherwise, torch.load() will fall back to the default behavior, as if
> map_location wasn’t specified.
>
> If map_location is a torch.device object or a string containing a
> device tag, it indicates the location where all tensors should be
> loaded.
>
> Otherwise, if map_location is a dict, it will be used to remap
> location tags appearing in the file (keys), to ones that specify where
> to put the storages (values).

Comment: So how do I do this in this case ? I tried :     self.load_state_dict(torch.load(directory / f'weights_{name}.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu')))      with still the same error ??

Comment: what is the error? You did not share the error

Comment: It looks like what I suggested and what you commented should fix the error. Are you positive this error is from the corrected code with map_location?

Comment: yes, I have tried it several times. Even tried it with differnt conda envs python 3.8 + 3.6 just in case. But no change. Is it problem with mobilenet ? I dont get it - this tool even has a benchmarking function for comparing cpu and gpu. So it has to work on cpu somehow.

Comment: It's not mobilenet, it's your code. So I would recommend creating a mini code snippet with harcdcoded values: `torch.load(PATH, map_location=torch.device("cpu"))`

Comment: great hint thank you very much - this worked. So I found 3 more places where I had to delete . cuda or add ('cpu) in all these modules. seemes to be hardcoded for available gpu